# How to remove feature on right click in openlayers 5

Tags: javascript, contextmenu, openlayers, openlayers-5

I have a feature on the map in openlayers, my requirement is to allow the user to remove the feature by right click.

Here is the reference screenshots :

[image: Hover on the feature]

[image: After right click]

When user clicks on "Remove", the feature should be removed.
If user clicks else where after the right click on feature, the "Remove" menu should disappear.

Here is the sample : [`openlayers` map with a feature](https://jsbin.com/nimopez/4/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: There is an extension too for contextmenu.[https://github.com/jonataswalker/ol-contextmenu]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to override the default content menu and add your own.  Add listeners to turn it off if the view changes, the users hits the esc key, etc.  Adding this code worked on your sample:

```
var contextMenu = document.createElement('div');
contextMenu.id = "contextMenu"
contextMenu.dir = "ltr";
contextMenu.className = "contextMenu";
contextMenu.style.position = "absolute";
contextMenu.style.left = "0px";
contextMenu.style.top = "0px";
contextMenu.style.display = "none";
map.getViewport().appendChild(contextMenu);

contextMenu.innerHTML = 
    '<div id="contextMenuRemove" class="menuItem" onclick="removeFeature();"> Remove </div>';

var mouseOver = false;

function hideContextMenu() {
    contextMenu.style.display = "none";
}

map.on('click', hideContextMenu);

map.getView().on('change', function () {
    if (contextMenu.style.display != "none") {
       setTimeout(hideContextMenu, 250);  // delay reset until map singleclick event has fired
    }
});

contextMenu.addEventListener('contextmenu', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});

document.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 27) {
        hideContextMenu();
    }
});

function openContextMenu(x, y) {
    contextMenu.style.right = "";
    contextMenu.style.bottom = "";
    contextMenu.style.left = x + "px";
    contextMenu.style.top = y + "px";
    contextMenu.style.display = "block";
}

var canvas = map.getViewport().getElementsByTagName("canvas")[0];
var features;

canvas.addEventListener('contextmenu', function (e) {
    features = map.getFeaturesAtPixel([e.x, e.y]);
    if (features) {
        e.preventDefault();
        openContextMenu(e.x, e.y);
    }
});

function removeFeature() {
    source.removeFeature(features[0]);
}
```

This is the style I use for context menus (in your case there were no disabled entries or separators)

```
.contextMenu {
    background-color: #eee;
    position: absolute;
    border: solid 1px black;
    width: 100px;
}
.contextMenu .menuItem {
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 5px;
}
.contextMenu .disabled {
    color: #aaa;
    pointer-events: none;
    cursor: none;
}
.contextMenu .menuItem:hover {
    background-color: #ccc;
}
.menuSeparator {
    border-bottom: solid 1px black;
}";
```